# Replacing Occurrences of Strings in NSMutableArray Only Working Once

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, enumeration, spritebuilder

I am confounded, and perhaps have missed something simple, but I can't find it.

I'll do this problem in theoretical, because I have done a test and still cannot get it to work with stripped down code. I am using SpriteBuilder, but that shouldn't be what is causing the issue - I can log the value I am getting in the text input, but simply cannot get that value into the array a second time - but enough ranting, time for some code.

Main.h

```
#import "Content.h"
#import "ReplaceMe.h"

@property Content *contentInstance;
@property ReplaceMe *replaceMeInstance;
```

Main.m

```
   -(void)someFunction{
    _contentInstance = (Content*)[CCBReader load:@"ContentScene"];
  [_contentInstance.changeArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([_contentInstance.base[idx] containsString:@"one"]){
            NSLog(@"I contain one!");
            NSString *replace = [_content.testArray[idx] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"one" withString:changeTheText.string];
            [_content.testArray replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:replace];
            NSLog(@"%@",_content.testArray[idx]);
        }
    }];
[_contentInstance updateLabels];
    }
```

Content.h

```
@property NSArray *base;
@property NSArray *changeArray;
```

Content.m

```
-(void)someFunction{
    _base = @[@"This is one",@"This is two",@"This is two point one"];
    _changeArray = [base mutableCopy];
}
-(void)updateLabels{
    [_changeArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        _labeler = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_changeArray[idx]] fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:12.0f];
        }
    }];
}
```

ReplaceMe.h

```
@property CCTextField *changeTheText;
-(void)_changeTheTextSelector;
```

ReplaceMe.m

```
-(void)_changeTheTextSelector{
self.visible=NO;
}
```

When I call MainScene's `someFuction`, this set up works just dandy the first time - and only the first time. I can't get `changeArray` to update after the first time I run the enumeration.

I know that `changeTheText` is changing, as it logs out, but when I log `changeArray[idx]`, it is stuck at the first `changeTheText`.

Any ideas?

Comment: why dont u try the old familiar for loop for enumeration and tell me the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this and compare with your code. it is working fine for me;

```
NSArray* base = @[@"This is one",@"This is two",@"This is two point one"];
NSMutableArray *changeArray = [base mutableCopy];

[base enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj containsString:@"one"]) {
        NSLog(@"data : %@", changeArray[idx]);
        //--
        [changeArray replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:[((NSString*) obj) stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"one" withString:@""]];
    }
}];

NSLog(@"changeArray %@", changeArray);
```

Comment: Shoaib, works like a charm, now. Your code was 100% on point. Thanks!